# Using Excel vba Macro to be run through Windows Schedule Task

Tags: vba, excel, scheduled-tasks

I have a Excel spreadsheet which I've set up a timer to run code into a database. If the spreadsheet is open and the time now is the time set within the timeslot then it exports the data into the database

I use this line in both my subroutine and the workbook_open `Application.OnTime TimeValue("22:00:00"), "ExportOpenJobs"`

This is great for when the spreadsheet is open, but I want to be able to set it through the Windows Schedule task.

I'm using Windows Server 2012 as my host pc and where the file is stored. Within the Task Scheduler I set the Action to Start a program and the Program script to the location and the actual *.xlsm file along with the start time for the Task. I set this task 30seconds before the time within the Excel VBA.

My problem is that the Windows Task Scheduler runs at the time set, after looking at the Task History I can see the Task Started/Completed and Action Started/Completed often taking around 50mins to complete, but when I check the database the Excel VBA hasn't run.

How can I get my Task Scheduler to run the Excel VBA code?

Within the Windows Server do you actually need to have Excel installed, therefore should it be done on another machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hello what I would do is create this .VBS file and then use Windows Task Scheduler to execute this vbs file at the desired interval.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Set myxlApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxlApplication.Visible = False
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( curDir & "\myTest.xlsm" ) 'Change to the actual workbook that has the Macro
myWorkBook.Application.Run "Module1.HelloWorld" 'Change to the Module and Macro that contains your macro
myxlApplication.Quit
```

[Application.Run Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

This example does require Excel to be installed on to the host running the scheduled task.  If that host is a Server or a Desktop computer is your choice.

The Windows Task Scheduler should be done as such for the Action portion of the task:

`Action: Start a program`

`Program/script: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe`

`Add arguments (optional): C:\Path_to_your_vbs\Your.vbs`

`Start in (optional): C:\Path_to_your_vbs\`

Comment: Thanks for this, what should I create this through? Visual Studio or similar?

Comment: Ignore previous comment, I googled it. So with setting the macro to run in this code I wouldn't need to use the Application.On Time event then?

Comment: That is correct in this case the VBS file is executing the Macro and Windows Task Scheduler is saying when to execute the Macro.  The VBS also tells Excel to quit and then the process will start a new when the next event in task scheduler occurs.

Comment: I've set this up and it's running, how long would it normally take to update around 800 rows using this process? I ask as it has now been running for 2 & 1/2 hours

Comment: Good question. You can debug it by changing the visible to true and comment out the quit line with a '. My suspicion is that the work book is asking to enable macros. Once it has done so once should be good enough.

Comment: I've switched the debug on, and set it running so we will see. If your suspicion is right how do we get it to enable macro's?

Comment: If that is a problem then Excel will ask you to enable them as soon as it opens the workbook.

Comment: I've had it on again for just over 2 hours and it's still runing, no erroring at all. It's set on a machine that is Windows 8 and with Excel 365 installed. The Excel is also set to enable macro's as I changed the permissions within Excel

Comment: After leaving it overnight and running for over 12 hours, still nothing has run, no messages nothing. Why is this not working?

Comment: The .vbs file can be executed at any time, it does not necessarily need to be executed via Windows Task Scheduler.  This script also assumes that the .vbs file is in the same directory as the excel workbook.  So in order to troubleshoot the problem you can execute the vbs file at any time and determine what doesn't happen.  Does excel open?  Does excel open the workbook?  Does excel execute the macro?  Which step does it fail at?

Comment: Also although the code is set up to execute a workbook in the same folder as the vbs file that does not have to be the case.  The vbs file can be anywhere but you do need to be sure that the Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( curDir & "\myTest.xlsm" ) line has the full path to the workbook.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you could run this file outside of the Windows Task Scheduler. Anyway after reading your post, I tested the vbs script on the Windows 8 machine. It loaded Excel and ran the macro that was inside the script. I then tested it on the Windows Server 2012, this doesn't have Excel Installed. When I double clicked it brought this error - ActiveX component can't create object: 'Excel.Application' Code 800A01AD. So I will just use it on the Windows 8 machine, but still dont understand why it doesnt run through the Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: That is correct the host does need Excel installed on it so if you install excel on the server it will work.  The problem with Windows Task Scheduler is that you will actually need to use Action: "Start a Program", Program/script: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe", Argument: "C:\Path_to_vbs\Your.vbs", "Start In: "C:\Path_to_vbs".  I will update the answer with that as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, this has been such a great help, After running the script separtley I see how it now runs and then updates my db using the macro. I test the Windows Task and yes this ran and completed the task as it you said it would. My problem is that the data never showed up in the database, like it had 2 mins before when I just ran the vbs script.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Task Scheduler set:
  Action: Start a Program
  Program Script: The Excel.exe with path in full quotes.
  Add Arguments: The workbook you want to open with full path in quotes

Check out this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/excel-files-can-not-be-opened-in-task-scheduler-in/aa6cf065-09ac-44d8-b6fb-a2f2ecd9b8cc

Worked for me after banging my head for a couple hours.