# Extract data from text and selfdestruct

Tags: excel, data-extraction, vba

I'm currently working at a Uni project using Excel VBA and I'm trying to find a way to create an excel that will self destruct if it doesn't find the "Key". And in the event it's entirely impossible, then at least ensure there's none of the data or VBA code left.

The idea is that, using

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim direct As String, name As String
    name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
    direct = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Call Checker(direct, name) 
End Sub
```

Upon opening the excel, it will look for "Key.txt" which should be within the same folder as the excel and check if the one string of text inside the document matches with "Code" which is a "Public Const" inside the project.

I've been trying to find a way to read the "Key.txt" without opening it, but haven't turned up anything.

On the other hand, I've been testing out various ways of making the program delete the original excel file, varying levels of success. So a somewhat roundabout way I've been testing out is to have the excel SaveAs a ".xlsx" and erase the original file before closing itself, but it doesn't work out as I've hoped for.

This is the code I've used for the "Self-Destruct" method:

```
Option Explicit
Function Checker(MyPath As String, name As String)

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim myPath2 As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FSO As Object

    myPath2 = MyPath

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\0_0.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "1"
    For Each ws In Worksheets  'Deletes all other sheets
        If ws.Name <> "1" Then ws.Delete
    Next

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    If Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = Left(MyPath, Len(MyPath) - 1)
    If FSO.FolderExists(MyPath) = False Then MsgBox MyPath & " doesn't exist"

    FSO.deletefile MyPath & "\" & name, True  'Deletes original file

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a self-destructing file is an interesting idea.  The short answer is that you cannot delete a running VBA macro. Therefore, no VBA macro can essentially self destruct. Yet, there are two options I can think of:

(1) Remove everything but the running macro. The following code might be helpful to achieve that.
http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbavbedeleteallmacros

(2) Close the file and ask Windows to delete the file afterwards for you using the task planner. The following post on SO might be able to help with that.
[Using Excel vba Macro to be run through Windows Schedule Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129613/using-excel-vba-macro-to-be-run-through-windows-schedule-task)

Other tempting solutions might be to save the file as .xlsx or to create a new Excel file, copy the above code from option 1 into that file, call the newly created code, which essentially deletes the original file.

But the real questions I'd ask myself would be: How did this person got the self-destructing file? Was it by email and the file is still in the email? Has the file been duplicated along the way? Are there hidden copies in some Temp-Folders (remember Excel Auto-Safe every xx minutes in case of computer crash to preserve your work)? Is the person enabling macros when opening the file (to allow self-destruction)? Can the person resore the file with the many free programs out there to recover files from a Windows machine (extremely easy as Windows does not delete the file or writes cryptical data on top to ensure it cannot be recovered, but merely "marks" that space on the HD where the file was as free to use for the next file to come)?

Comment: The short answer to your question is that this is an experimental Univeristy project. We're supposed to make a file impossible to be manually accessed, specially whatever VBA codes are in it. So I thought that aside from standard encryption and protection of the VBA code, making it Self-Destructible would be as good as it got. Also, would you happen to know how to make it read the "txt" file?

Comment: To read an external txt file you might want to look at the following solution here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140659/vba-excel-macro-to-update-list-via-external-file/31141373#31141373

Comment: Note that any security you choose is only as good as the software enforcing it. If you open the .xls file with Microsoft Excel, the all security mechanisms will be enforced as intended. But there are many other programs out there which do not do that. To access the VBA code simply open an .xls file using OpenOffice or LibreOffice or something similar (where no protection is enforced on VBA).

Comment: Thanks, also, the "Turn excel into .xslx" idea was already implemented into the code. I'll try to see what I can find and I'll post the results.