# Schedule complex Macro(.xlsm) Task on Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I have an xlsm file, which consist 12 modules, and each module contains several functions. But my first module (Macro_Caller)

[image]

contains 4 Sub procedures, I want to run them one by one, how would I go about that. I tried to write VBS file and a bat file to do it, however it is not working properly.

```
**VBS File Code**

Dim args, eApp

Set args = wscript.Arguments
set eApp = GetObject("Fiile_Path\Send Now Final.xlsm")

eApp.visible = True

eApp.Run = "Sub Procedure Name"

eApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
eApp.ActiveWorkbook.close(0)
eApp.Quit
```

**.Bat File Code**

```
cscript SendNow.vbs "File_Path\Send Now Final.xlsm"
```

Comment: Please note that *"is not working properly"* is no useful error description. Whad exactly does not work? What errors do you get? • Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24130088/3219613) if it helps you.

Comment: "I want to run them one by one" - create a single sub in your workbook which calls them, then run that from your sript.